# error: missing return statement 3

Tags: java, return

What should I put as my return statement for the method overall since i'm already using return statements in my if/else?

```
public static boolean rowsAreValid(int[][] array){
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            for (int k = i +1; k < array.length; k++){
                for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                    // Returns false if the numbers are not the same
                    if (array[i][j] == array[k][j]){
                        System.out.println("false");
                        return false;
                    }
                    //Returns true if numbers are the  same
                    else {
                        System.out.println("true");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // RETURN STATEMENT
    }
```

Comment: Either your comments are wrong or the test is wrong, because you're returning false if the numbers are the same while the comment says the opposite. Also, I think the second for should be testing array[i].length and the third array[i][k].length.

Comment: What happens if array is null? In this case, your for loops won't run and no return statement will be executed. Maybe, you can correct this first and try it out

Comment: In addition to what the others have noted, this looks like it will actually only compare 2 numbers, not loop through the whole array.

Answer (score 2):

This code is confusing, but at the level of why the compiler complains (without addressing the overall structure of the code):  You could have a case where the loops don't execute, and if this happens, your if-else block will never execute and you don't have a return.  This will happen, for example, if `array.length == 0`. You need to decide what the right answer is for this method in those cases and provide a return accordingly.

Comment: Or if any of the subarrays are of length 0 (although I think the tests in the for loops are wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to return `true` when the numbers are the same, then put in your return statement: `return true`. Because by reasoning, your numbers will never be not the same.

Also as @blm noted on the comments, I think the snippet in your code:

```
// Returns false if the numbers are not the same
if (array[i][j] == array[k][j]){
    ...
}
```

Should be,

```
// Returns false if the numbers are not the same
if (array[i][j] != array[k][j]){
    ...
}
```

Because otherwise, your logic would be incorrect.